# DataNucleus: how to remove type mappings of java.awt.* on android

Tags: java, android, types, awt, datanucleus

DataNucleus on android, runtime error:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;

at org.datanucleus.store.types.TypeManagerImpl.loadJavaTypes(TypeManagerImpl.java:1055)

at org.datanucleus.store.types.TypeManagerImpl.<init>(TypeManagerImpl.java:154)

at org.datanucleus.AbstractNucleusContext.getTypeManager(AbstractNucleusContext.java:230)

at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManagerImpl.<init>(MetaDataManagerImpl.java:227)

at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.metadata.JPAMetaDataManager.<init>
```

According to the following link, there are many types not available on android

http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jpa/mapping.html

java.awt is not available on android. Is there a way to remove the mappings not supported on android? type mapping configuration?

Comment: I doubt you can without updating the source code. If you have a list of classes that are not present in Android, but are in their codebase then why not contribute something that checks whether it is Android in use, and so they can then not load support for those types? Of the types listed on that page, the majority of the "java.awt" are geometry types and only present in their "geospatial" plugin, so you will never see errors for those since won't be loaded anyway

Comment: Can the geospatial plugin be removed? plugins are usually pluggable. If type mappings are added by plugins, they should be removed without affecting the rest of code. Thanks.

Comment: Looked at https://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/datanucleus/store/types/TypeManagerImpl.java, the java.awt.image.BufferedImage is built-in type mapping.

Comment: "geospatial removed" ? It's you who decides if you put it in the CLASSPATH, so why do you need to remove it?!

Comment: Why should I look at that? I suggested that you get the code and contribute some update, with a check for whether android was being used. I also suggested that you find out ALL classes that are not in Android, so then your update can include all such classes

Comment: It seems that geospatial is not a plugin, it is in the core.

Comment: Of course geospatial is a PLUGIN! https://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-geospatial   http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-geospatial/

Comment: I do not know why spatial types such as java.awt.BufferedImage are mapped in the core, not in the plugin. The core should contain very basic common mappings only.

Comment: BufferedImage is an IMAGE, not a "spatial type"!